# Batch if/else statements

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I am currently writing a batch file to create, edit, and delete journal entries for an internship I'm currently working on, I don't seem to understand how to get my if/else statements to work, this is my first time using batch, most of the coding I have done has either been in Linux or Python, so maybe I'm just making a dumb mistake:

```
:edit
echo Welcome to the editing menu!
echo To edit a journal entry, enter the date of the journal below in a MM-DD-YYYY format! (I.E. 05-8-1982)
powershell sleep 3
set /p filename2=What is the date of the entry you are looking for?
echo Searching for file now... 
powershell sleep 1
if EXIST "%filename2%.txt" G:\Batch\JournalEntries\*
(
start "%filename2%.txt"
)
ELSE (
ECHO not found
```

From this point, when I run the program and get to the editing menu, I am asked to enter a filename. I put it in and then a new cmd window opens with the filename I've entered, as it is unable to find the name I entered (This is done on purpose, I am testing whether it will give me the else error or not).

Comment: First, there is a `timeout` command to stop for a while, e.g. try `timeout /T sec` where you replace `sec` with some seconds. Second, you cannot check if multiple files exist in a single `if` statement. I am going to write an answer for you to see it better as I can't format anything in comments.

Comment: OH i just noticed a mistake in my own code, let me edit that real quick

Comment: Have you made a mistake quoting two times `%filename2%.txt`? Quotes in filenames aren't allowed!

Comment: Updated with more explanation double-beep

Comment: Your problem should be gone with my answer. Let me know if it doesn't work; leave a comment below it.

Comment: Is `05-8-1982` really in `MM-DD-YYYY` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fixed code must look like:

```bat
:edit
echo Welcome to the editing menu!
echo To edit a journal entry, enter the date of the journal below in a MM-DD-YYYY format! (I.E. 05-8-1982)
timeout /T 3 >nul
set /p "filename2=What is the date of the entry you are looking for? "
echo Searching for file now... 
timeout /T 1 >nul
if exist "%filename2%.txt" (
    if exist "G:\Batch\JournalEntries\*" (
        start "" "%filename2%.txt"
    ) else (
        echo Did not found files matching pattern G:\Batch\JournalEntries\*!
    )
) else (
    echo Did not found files matching pattern %filename2%.txt!
)
pause
```

Just some notes:

- There is a `timeout` command in batch: it is used to wait for a specified period. Alternative: `ping`.
- Quote `var` and `value` when setting variables like `set "var=value"`. Use the same format even if there are `/a` or `/p` options.
- You seem to misunderstand the `if` command usage. At least one parenthesis should be in the same line as `if`; see the above code block for more details.
- It is good not to write with upper-case in batch. It just makes noise as it is a case-insensitive language.
- It seems you made a mistake quoting `%filename2%.txt` file quoting both filename and filename and extension. Since quotes aren't allowed as a file/foldername, I have removed and just double-quoted filename and extension.

For more information about the commands used, please type in `cmd.exe`:

- `echo /?`
- **`timeout /?`** explains its usage
- `ping /?` alternative to `timeout`
- **`if /?`** explains syntax and usage of `if`
- `start /?`

Comment: Alright so I tried that and it definitely works better than what I had, my batch is definitely not up-to-par. It did come up with new issues though. WHen testing it both with an invalid date and a valid date, I came up with the else statement. 
for my test I used a file named 04-04-1999.txt
tested first with random date (06-18-1893) and came up with the else statement which I had loop back to the beginning. Then using an existing file (04-04-1999) I tried and came up with the same else statement

Comment: wait, I made a new edit and now when I put in a correct date it instead just exits the command line without opening the file

Comment: @doublebeep when I reach the else statement I set it to goto the beginning of the editing menu. The reason I want it to check for that path is so it is able to open that file named the date specified in that path, I have all the files in the folder JournalEntries, which later on after I get all my separate menu options for my script finished Im going to attempt to have the program create a folder called JournalEntries if it does not exist, allow the user to create files inside the said folder, be able to edit them through the edit menu, and be able to read a specified file within the script

Comment: After removal all that happens when I get to that point is that it works perfectly fine and then doesnt give me any time to read the output of the start command running as it immediately closes the command line